# how to setup ssd in a hdd laptop without opening it up

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, ssd

I(my parents) purchased a laptop last may for online classes but because im a curious teenager , i installed alot of heavy softwares like blender and unity and did a lot of heavy rendering (which my dad suggest , has slowed down my laptop alot) and indeed , it takes up to 1 - 2 minutes to open the laptop and also it takes another few minutes after startup for the laptop to come out of the dizzy phase where it does not respond well.

specs : 
processor : Intel Core  i5-8250U 1.6GHz 1.80 GHz
RAM : 4gb
64 bit
no touch screen

According to a few people i asked , i should replace the hdd to a ssd
So is there a way i can just plug the ssd externally(without opening a single screw) and use it for startup so that my laptop is much more responsive
**EDIT**
It is a HP 14q
Some more info , as it appears , my laptop ahs only 2 scewrs at its back and no other openable panel(as far as i can see :))

Comment: What is your laptop's model and what external ports does it have?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: no. You (or anyone else) does need to open the laptop, physically replace the hdd for an ssd and either reinstall windows, or clone the harddisk.

Windows does not want to be installed to an external disk, nor will it boot from it. Windows To-Go is an exception but that is not a route you want to take either.

Do note, given the harddrive is the most replaced part in any computer, most laptops make it really easy to access the laptop without opening up the entire back. Like one or two screws that gives access to a rectangle panel with the hdd below it. Others make the entire back be able to get off easily and the hdd is accessible then.

How it works for your laptop is really hard to say without knowing the brand and type, so I can't give any advise on that.

That said, most physical stores that sell drives can help you build in the new drive, though if those stores don't have a special department for maintenance, I'm not sure if they can also clone the drive. But if they do, that is definitely the thing you want to do. Keep in mind that most stores will not allow you to wait for it, so you bring the laptop and they will build in the ssd and clone it for you and a few days later, they call you and you can come and pick up the laptop again.

That said, given that your laptop is from last may, there is a fair chance you already have an SSD in your computer. When an SSD reaches 100% storage capacity, it will slow down to a crawl. So before taking any action, ensure you really don't have an SSD already. If you do have an SSD, make sure at least 25% of free space is available, more is preferable, then defrag it using Defraggler (don't use windows' build in defrag, won't work on SSD's) and it should become speedy again. Then you can put data back, just ensure you have at least 25% free space to keep it speedy. You can store less important stuff on an external drive, or consider to upgrade to a larger SSD. The first part of this post applies again then.

Comment: For your laptop its a rather complicated sequence of steps. If you don't feel comfortable in following an instruction manual, you are better of getting your laptop serviced. See: https://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c04336109